# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list even when code is correct

Tags: javascript, php, syntax, arguments

Iam getting the above error. I have checked my syntax. There is nothing seems to be missing in the code.

```
1  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   2       $(document).ready(function(){
   3       
   4       $('#submit').on('click',function(){

   5      var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
   6     var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
   7      $.ajax({
   8     type:'POST',
   9     url:'date_based_report_action.php',
   10    data:'from_date='+from_date+'&to_date='+to_date,
   11    success:function(html){
   12    alert(html);
   13   $('#tabledata').html(html);  
   14   }
   15   });
   16   }
   17   }); 
   18   </script>
```

The error shows in Line no.16 when I check the console.

Comment: on 16 line you are missing `)` i.e : `});` you have not close your `$('#submit').on('click',function(){..`

Comment: Neatly indented code might have highlighted the issue for you.

Comment: BTW, the *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 3 over 20 years ago, it's subsequently been removed. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 16 ad this ); , you are missing to close function $('#submit').on('click',function(){ complete code below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').on('click', function() {

    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'date_based_report_action.php',
      data: 'from_date=' + from_date + '&to_date=' + to_date,
      success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
        $('#tabledata').html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```